# Salvar vídeo MP4 sem audio

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia salvar um clip(vídeo) em MP4 pela biblioteca FFMPeg-PHP sem o audio, pois o mesmo não será necessário e gostaria de diminuir tambem o tamanho do arquivo.

Estou usando a seguinte lógica:

```
$frame = $segundos/6;
    for($i = 1 ; $i <= 5 ; $i++){
        $format = new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
        $format->setAudioCodec('libmp3lame');
        $clip = $video->clip(\FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds($frame*$i), \FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(2.5));
        $clip->filters()->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240), \FFMpeg\Filters\Video\ResizeFilter::RESIZEMODE_INSET, true);
        $clip->save($format,TEMPDIR.DS.'thumb.'.$filename.'_'.$i.'.mp4');
    }


$video->concat([TEMPDIR.DS.'thumb.'.$filename.'_1.mp4',
                TEMPDIR.DS.'thumb.'.$filename.'_2.mp4',
                TEMPDIR.DS.'thumb.'.$filename.'_3.mp4',
                TEMPDIR.DS.'thumb.'.$filename.'_4.mp4',
                TEMPDIR.DS.'thumb.'.$filename.'_5.mp4'])
      ->saveFromSameCodecs(TEMPDIR.DS.'thumb.'.$filename.'.mp4', TRUE);
```

Mas não vi nada na documentação sobre salvar sem algo sem audio, até porque para salvar o clip é obrigatório setar um AudioCodec se não da erro de encoding.

Comment: Não funciona, da o erro: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264::addFilter()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você remove áudio usando o sinalizador `-an`.

```
ffmpeg -i example.mkv -c copy -an example-nosound.mkv
```

Use como base o código abaixo para remover o áudio com o SimpleFilter.

```
$customFilter = '-an';
\FFMpeg::fromDisk($disk)
->open($input)
->addFilter(new FFMpeg\Filters\Audio\SimpleFilter([$customFilter]))
->export()
->toDisk([$outputdisk])
->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264'))
->save($output);
```

> Referências
>
> [Proper use of setAdditionalParameters to remove audio?](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/issues/365)
>
> [Remove audio from video file with FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/268985/remove-audio-from-video-file-with-ffmpeg)
>
> Nota
>
> [Converting Audio into Different Formats / Sample Rates](https://gist.github.com/protrolium/e0dbd4bb0f1a396fcb55)
>
> [Documentação PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/tree/master/docs/source/API/API)

Comment: No caso, o que entraria no $disk e $outputdisk? o $Input acredito que seja o caminho real da midia correto?

Comment: É um exemplo de uso do simplefilter, export, save, fromdisk, são funções usadas no laravel, foque nos filtros e formats e tente no teu codigo. Mas acredito que seria mais facil fazer no cli essa retirada de audio.

Comment: Consegui salvar o vídeo sem audito adicionar a linha: $clip->addFilter(new \FFMpeg\Filters\Audio\SimpleFilter(['-an'])); Obrigado Darlei.